# Pinescript returns "Internal server pine compilation error"

Tags: pine-script

I encountered a problem: The pine code cannot be executed after being compiled because the code is too long (close to 1000 lines). The specific error is: "Internal server pine compilation error".  When I delete some content arbitrarily, it can be run normally after saving and compiling, so I infer that the code is too long.  What should I do about this problem? Ask the TV pine working group for help.  Thank you！

Comment: There are can be many reasons for this error. I suggest to contact with TV Support for fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Morning boda_vida,

I too had a similar problem, once I reviewed the code and got some help on the forum I had repeated a lot of code that could be consolidated as it did the same calculations.

[How to apply formula to several securities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65858641/how-to-apply-formula-to-several-securities)

Have a look at the above link.

If you share some of your code it will make it a lot easier for the forum to assist you.