# Is it possible to use yesterday's POC value from volume profile session volume?

Tags: pine-script

I am going to create an indicator which uses yesterday's POC price ( from tradingview's built in Volume Profile (session volume)) as support resistance .
I wonder if it is possible to use it as a price value to compare with current price . Is this viable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4season,

I have recently used previous days Point of Control (pdPOC) and day before yesterdays Point of Control (dbyPOC) as plots in my recent script (below).

https://uk.tradingview.com/script/AHNKTwcK-Trading-Ideas-Chart-Champions-Value-Points-of-Interest/

The code might assist you with your goals.

But when you say "compare with current price" can you expand and explain this further.

As in a percentage compare?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, no I am not looking for percentage compare . The source code you just sent me solved my problem .

Comment: @4season if my answer completed your question I would be grateful if you could tick the answered button next to my input. Also this code might assist you with your percentage element. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65858641/how-to-apply-formula-to-several-securities
I would be interested in your end solution as I am keen to use POC more.

Comment: I did so, actually there is no additional solution and I just used your sourcecode .